# when formal parameter is variable of some class type what data types can be corresponding actual parameters

Tags: java

Could someone please answer the following two questions for me.

1. When formal parameter is variable of some class type what data types can be corresponding  actual parameters?
2. When formal parameter is variable of an interface type what data types can be corresponding actual parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1)when formal parameter is variable of some class type what data types
>   can be corresponding actual parameters?

I hope you mean the object type of some class. The method will accept any object of the class mentioned and any of its subclasses.

> 2) when formal parameter is variable of an interface type what data
>   types can be corresponding actual parameters?

The method will accept the object type of any class implementing that interface